# Ternary operator. && does not work. Laravel, Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, ternary

I have an `image Storage` that stores `images` from users' personal pages. The name of the image is also stored in the `img` field of the `users` table in the database. I want to show it if there is a `name` in `DB` and an `image` in `storage`, otherwise I want to show a default image. I tried this but `&&` doesn't work. I guess I'm doing something wrong:

```
<img src="{{ ((Auth::user()->img) && (Storage::url('users/'.Auth::user()->img))) ? (Storage::url('users/'.Auth::user()->img)) : '/img/svg/laptop-house-solid.svg' }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was in different types of data. In the database I had a string, and in Storage there was an object (if I call it correctly) i.e. image, so the check didn't work. You can use the `Storage::exists()` facade function to check if an image exists.

```
<img src="{{ ((Auth::user()->img) && (Storage::disk('public')->exists('users/'.Auth::user()->img))) ? (Storage::url('users/'.Auth::user()->img)) : '/img/svg/laptop-house-solid.svg' }}">
```